# Is there any relation between distance from source to reflector and standing waves?

Tags: electromagnetic, microwave, reflection

When two electromagnetic waves (not considering mechanical waves) having the same amplitude and wavelength, moving in opposite directions are superimposed on each other and create standing waves. One way to create standing waves is through reflection. Is there any relation between distance from source to reflector and standing waves or they can create at any distance?

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there any relation between distance from source to reflector and
> standing waves or they can create at any distance?*

The distance from the source to the reflector doesn't alter the standing wave effect i.e. close to the reflector if the standing wave ratio is \$x\$ then it will be so no matter what distance the source is.

Obviously there are some things that can muddle the picture such as if the source is quite close to the reflector (a couple of wavelengths or less) because near-field effects can shadow true standing waves.